# Generic Method Constraint of child class issue

Tags: c#

First here's the break down of the class hierarchy:

```
public class Entity {
}

public abstract class AuditBase<T> {
   protected abstract void SomeMethod();
}

public class EntityAudit : AuditBase<Entity> {
   protected override void SomeMethod() {
   }
}
```

Then, I have a method with a constraint like so:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> Query<T>(int id) where T : AuditBase<T>
{
  var instance = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
  var refTable = instance.RefTable;

  var collection = _context.Database.GetCollection<T>("Audit");
  var filter = String.Join("{ RefTable: '", refTable, "', Object: { Id: {'$eq': ", id.ToString(), "} } }");

  return await collection.FindSync<T>(filter).ToListAsync();
}
```

However, I get an error when I use the following code:

```
var result = await Query<EntityAudit>(5);
```

The error is:

```
The type 'EntityAudit' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type of method 'Audit.Query<T>(int)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'EntityAudit' to 'AuditBase<EntityAudit>'.
```

I kind of understand the issue.  My goal is really to restrict the returned `IEnumerable` to *only* contain objects that are **children of** `AuditBase`.  Currently, it's trying to return items of type 'Entity' due to `T`.

I can't do the constraint as so: `... where T: Audit` as `Audit` "requires one parameter."

Any thoughts?  How do I implement the constraint?

#### EDIT:

So I ended up doing the following:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> Query<T,U>(int id) where T: AuditBase<U>
{
  ...
}

var result = await Query<EntityAudit, Entity>(5)
```

This works.

**But, is there a better way?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a non generic audit base base class

```
//...

public abstract class AuditBase {
 //...
}

public abstract class AuditBase<T> : AuditBase {
   protected abstract void SomeMethod();
}

//...
```

and use that for the constraint

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> Query<T>(int id) where T : AuditBase {
    //...
}
```